# Prevent loading script file after ajax append?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have make countdown function `timeload` for `quiz.php`.When click `submit` and call ajax ,I appended update body html by `$('body').html(d);` **in that case `quiz.js` is also loaded ,so variable `countdown` value is reinitialize**! That is the problem ,so can I prevent appending script file after ajax called in `.html()`

**quiz.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    //next click 
    $(':submit').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();          
            data = $('form').serialize() + "&submit=" + $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                url :"quiz.php",
                data : data,                
                type : "POST",
                success : function (d) {
                    $('body').html(d); //reload `quiz.js` 
               }
            });    
    }); 
    var countdown = 1 * 60 * 1000; //Here problem -> after ajax called reinitialize value 
    var timeload = setInterval(function () {
        countdown -= 1000;
        var min = Math.floor(countdown / (60 * 1000));
        var sec = Math.floor((countdown - (min * 60 * 1000)) / 1000);

        if (countdown <= 0) {
            alert("5 min!");
            clearInterval(timeload);               
        } else {
            $("#time").html(min + " : " + sec);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: can you add `return false` at last of click function

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by `in that case quiz.js is also loaded ,so variable countdown value is reinitialize!`

Comment: @CerlinBoss Sorry , countdown is set to 1 minutes at first but after ajax call, its also reset to 1 minutes because of ajax is reloaded js file ! That is problem for me .So need to prevent loading js file after ajax called

Comment: @DavidJawphan: how is the reload happening? `$('body').html(d);` is re injecting the same js file? if so, put the js inside `<head></head>`

Comment: If the `quiz.js` reloads then all variable values inside it will reset, you can't stop that. The snippet you shared, is it from one `quiz.js` you are talking about?